# SELECT on full model fails because some columns are created in a later migration

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-6, migration, dbmigrator

I'm using Entity Framework 6 with SQLite and https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite.EF6.Migrations. `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled` is disabled. In `update-method` I call `Migrator.Update(pendingMigration);` for each pending migration.

The first migrations run without problems. Then an error occurs because an SQL query selects all columns of a model, but some of these are created in later migrations. The select statement should only contain the columns that are already created and not the full model. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the error happening while running your migrations? If so, then please include the code for the migration that is failing in your question